# How to iterate the loop if the condition is not met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the id of respective movie name in that i need to check whether the url is working or not . If not then i need to append the movie name in the empty list

```
data = {'id': [nan, nan, nan,nan],
            'movie_name': ['captain-fantastic', 'passengers', 'transformers','guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2']}


data2 = {'id': [nan, nan, nan,nan],
        'movie_name': ['captain-fantastic', 'passengers', 'transformers','guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol.2']}

dfa = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfa2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

from turtle import clear
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as ur, json

movie_buff_uuid= []

for i in dfa["movie_name"]:
    url = ur.urlopen("https://www.moviebuff.com/"+str(i)+".json")
    d = json.loads(url.read())['uuid']
    movie_buff_uuid.append(d)
```

print(movie_buff_uuid)

if i passed the data2 in the above loop i am getting this error urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found to overcome this error. I have tried this

```
movie_buff_uuid= []

for i in dfa["movie_name"]:
    url = ur.urlopen("https://www.moviebuff.com/"+str(i)+".json")
    if url.getcode() == 404:
       d = json.loads(url.read())['uuid']
    else:
        d = i

movie_buff_uuid.append(d)
     
print(movie_buff_uuid)
```

Expected output:

```
['f8379c86-1307-4b22-b175-5000284ef6b9', '8f0c611a-4356-454d-a6d6-aac437519540', '7cd2dffa-cb31-4897-a7b0-30dcaee66104', 'guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol.2']
```

Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: Dude, why are you loading the JSON into a dataframe to begin with?

Comment: In that website the data is in json format so i have used in the beginning @JoshFriedlander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dominik-air said, you're getting a 404 response when the file doesn't exist. However Python's built-in `urllib` raises an error when it gets this (unlike, for example, the justly popular `requests` library).

In Python generally we use try/catch flow to deal with this ([EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=forgiveness%20permission#term-EAFP)).

Putting it all together:

```
import json
from time import sleep
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.request import urlopen

movie_buff_uuid = []
movies = ['captain-fantastic', 'passengers', 'transformers','guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2']

for movie in movies:
    try:
        url = urlopen(f"https://www.moviebuff.com/{movie}.json")
        uuid = json.loads(url.read())['uuid']
        movie_buff_uuid.append(uuid)
    except HTTPError:
        movie_buff_uuid.append(movie)
    sleep(5)  # let's avoid hitting the server too heavily
```

(You don't need dataframes in the first part either :) )

Answer (score 1):

To check if a given url is valid you can read the status code of the request.
A 404 HTTP status code would mean that the site doesn't exist.
Example usage with your set of variables:

```
for i in dfa['movie_name']:
    url = ur.urlopen("https://www.moviebuff.com/"+str(i)+".json")
    if url.getcode() == 404:
        # insert code you want to run here
```

Comment: And in case you do need to get the UUID, don't use Pandas, it's just `json.loads(url.read())['uuid']`

Comment: Thanks @JoshFriedlander withouut using pandas its working fine

Comment: @dominik-air i have tried still i am getting the error HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: @JoshFriedlander and dominik-air i have modified the code kindly check